# How can i know if it's the last iteration of for loop?

Tags: python

```
s = "Some string"
for i in s.split():
    print(i)
    word += i[::-1]
    word += " "
```

Expected Output:
"emoS gnirts"

Output:
"emoS gnirts "

How can I know if it's the last loop so i can avoid adding a " " to my word?

Comment: an easier way might be to simply always remove the last character.

Comment: It is perhaps easier to check that you're operating on the first element (or not), and then add the space at the *beginning* of the loop when it's not the first element.

Comment: yeah but i was looking for a more optimal solution

Comment: You shouldn't do that anyway, use `str.join` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the shortest and fastest way:

```
>>> ' '.join(s[::-1].split()[::-1])
'emoS gnirts'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could know when it's the last loop is by storing the number of words in a variable and then using an if statement to see when the last word hits. Something like this:

```
    s = "Some string"
    word=""
    count = 0
    sLen = len(s.split())

    for i in s.split():  
        print(i)
        word += i[::-1]
        if not (count == (sLen - 1)):
            word += " "
        else:
            print("last loop")
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a reference, that'll be the way I will do it:

```
s = "some string"
word = ' '

word = ' '.join(s[::-1] for s in s.split())  # generator expression and join
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative;

```
myString = "Some string"
print(' '.join(''.join(reversed(word)) for word in myString.split()))
emoS gnirts
```

Comment: Why use a worse way to reverse a word?

Comment: I only wanted to let him/her know possible alternative to reverse a string. Indeed it is not the best way to reverse a string.

Answer (score -1):

What I usually do is put an `if` statement comparing the iterable's length to the iteration number. Like this:

```
word = ''
s = "Some string"
for e, i in enumerate(s.split()):
    print(i)
   
    word += i[::-1]

    if not (len(s.split()) - 1) == e:

        word += " "

 #proof the last character is 's' and not a space
 print(word[-1])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in many ways, but generally, in python, people prefer using the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) construction.

```pytho
s = "Some string"
for index, i in enumerate(s.split()):
    print(i)
    word += i[::-1]
    if index < len(s.split()) - 1:
        word += " "
```

Comment: Splitting the string over and over and over again is not exactly efficient.